# How to show that this equation has is distinct for each $\{1,2,...,p-1\}$?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $p$ is prime and $d|p-1$ with $d>0$ then $$x^{\frac{p-1}{d}}$$ takes on $d$ distinct values mod $p$ on $\{1,2,...,p-1\}$.

What I have done so far: Raise to the power of $d$ to get $x^{p-1}$. Now $x^{p-1}\equiv0$ has at most $p-1$ distinct solutions mod $p$. The only hint I have is to use Fermat's little theorem but I am unsure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem converning the number of solutions of a polynomial equation?

Comment: Yes. That is why I stated that $x^{p-1}\equiv0$ has at most $p-1$ distinct solutions.

Comment: Why do you write $\equiv 0$ ? Do you mean $\equiv 1$?

Comment: I believe both statements are true. The $\equiv 0$ version is true more generally and since $p$ is prime and $d|p-1$ in fact $x^{p-1}\equiv 1$ has $p-1$ solutions.

Comment: I don't understand why you emphasize that $x^{p-1} \equiv 0$ has at most $p-1$ distinct solutions. It should be clear (by for instance Fermat, or existence of inverses) that it has only one solution, namely $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We let $\mathbb{F}_p := \{0, \dots , p-1\}$. Now for each $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ let $S_a := \{ x \in \mathbb{F}_p \, \mid \, x^\frac{p-1}{d} \equiv a\}$

What does Lagrange's theorem say about the size of the set $S_a$ ?

What does Lagrange's theorem say about how many of the sets $S_a$ are nonempty? Hint: Any such a satisfies $a^d \equiv 1$

Now what should be a bound on the size of $\underset{a \in \mathbb{F}_p} \cup S_a$ according to the answers to the two preceding questions? When does the size equal its bound? Can you also argue what should be the exact size of$\underset{a \in \mathbb{F}_p} \cup S_a$?